# SonarQube custom plugin - create rule for measure

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am new to SonarQube and want to make a custom plugin to make some custom rules and measures.

My project contains a json file (report.json) where all important measures of the project are listed. Now I want to take one of these measures in the file and let SonarQube check if this value is greater than a certain threshold or lower.

I've already checked out [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example) template but I'm not sure which steps I need to make and which SonarQube API classes I have to use to make it work.

In detail it looks as follows:

I have a json file (report.json) and want to take the value of the key `numericValue`:

```
...
"numericValue": 251.84199999999998,
...
```

Now I want to check with SonarQube if this value is greater than 250 or lower than 250. Based on this a custom rule in SonarQube should pass or fail.

I have already looked at the documentation ([here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/) and [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/custom-measures/)) but it didn't help me much.